IFormFile not supported
To use IFormFile, we have to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http package, but it is deprecated in .NET 8. How to solve this problem?
I tried to add IFormFile to upload an image. But to add IFormFile, I need to reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, but it is deprecated in .Net 8.
I also tried to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.App, but it is throwing an error

The package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref 8.0.4 has a package type DotnetPlatform that is incompatible with this project


When I'm creating the .NET 8 ASP.NET MVC project the Visual Studio automatically adds  reference to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App shared framework and this is enough to use the IFormFile in my project. I'm not receiving any deprecating messages.
This interface declared in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http namespace that is part of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App shared framework.
For an additional information see Use the ASP.NET Core shared framework

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is also marked deprecated in Nuget.  Frustrated that there isn't any guidance on a path forward

@drewid: The Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is part of the Framework and not the NuGet package. In the answer above I didn't advise to use any packages. The IFormFile interface is already included to the framework SDK. For more details see the documentation: Use the ASP.NET Core shared framework
